# jquery .slideUp div keeps sliding back down

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my 'sales bar' to slid-up after the user click the close 'x' button.

it was all working fine -with the close button - but then I added a form, and if I put the close button inside the form (to get it in-line) then the slideUp only last a second, and the bar slides back down - it should stay 'gone'.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .top-general-alert {
        padding: 8px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
        background-color: #00294e;
        color: #ffee7a;
    }

    .top-general-alert {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .top-general-alert a,
    .top-general-alert a:hover {
        color: #0099cc;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="top-general-alert" >
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newsletter">Sign-up for our newsletter! </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="newsletter" placeholder="Your Email...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign-up!</button> <button class="close-top-general-alert" >&times;</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ( $('.top-general-alert').length > 0 ) {

        $('.top-general-alert').delay(800).slideDown('medium');

        $('.close-top-general-alert').click( function() {
            $('.top-general-alert').slideUp('fast');
        });

    }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(credit to https://www.buildersociety.com/threads/hellobar-free-alternative-devseries.1519/)

To be clear; If I make this modification (below) moving the close button outside the form. The behavior is correct. But the button is below the form

```
<div class="top-general-alert" >
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newsletter">Sign-up for our newsletter! </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="newsletter" placeholder="Your Email...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign-up!</button> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

×

Answer (score 0):

How about `hide()` after `slideUp()`?

```
$('.top-general-alert').slideUp('fast').hide('fast');
```

EDIT: `form` buttons cause page reload. Add `type=button` or `type=reset` will do work.

Full example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ( $('.top-general-alert').length > 0 ) {

        $('.top-general-alert').delay(800).slideDown('medium');

        $('.close-top-general-alert').click( function() {
            $('.top-general-alert').slideUp('fast').hide('fast');
        });

    }

});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.top-general-alert {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    background-color: #00294e;
    color: #ffee7a;
}

.top-general-alert {
    color: #fff;
}

.top-general-alert a,
.top-general-alert a:hover {
    color: #0099cc;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-general-alert" >
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newsletter">Sign-up for our newsletter! </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="newsletter" placeholder="Your Email...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign-up!</button> <button type="reset" class="close-top-general-alert" >&times;</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still slides back down

Comment: It's working here(see the snippet). Where are you trying to run your code on? CodePen?

Comment: I can make another working example here https://jsbin.com/safuwagedu/edit?html,output

Comment: Im running locally - exact code as posted - firefox 61.0.1

Comment: Yes - I see it works in your example - but it still keep sliding down on my localhost... FF and chrome. source says I am even using the 3.3.1 you used.

Comment: Because those are buttons in `form`, it'll try to send data every time your click the button. It means it actually **reload** the page.

Comment: Beautiful NoobTW5 - thx, setting the type="button" on the close button did the trick - good catch !!! thx - Change the text of your answer to reflect that - and I'll upvote and select it as answer.